# Keep trailing zero after using LEFT function in VBA

Tags: vba

I'm trying to figure out how to keep the trailing zero after a decimal in a set of numbers that is being extracted from a string of numbers with decimals. First I determine the position of the second decimal and then use the LEFT function to extract everything before. Ideally I want the extracted numbers to stay the way it was in the string but some have trailing zeros and some don't (ie 23.1 is different from 23.10). Right now the results of my code drops the trailing zeros.

Edit: The result cannot have any other additions to it as it will be used in a vlookup.

Examples of what the results should be:

```
String: 23.10.847475993.38.12039

Result: 23.10

String: 23.1.875934.28301.23814

Result: 23.1
```

Here is my code:

```
Dim Datastring  As String
Dim PeriodPosition As Integer

Datastring = Cells(i, 26).Value
PeriodPosition = InStr(1, Datastring, ".", vbTextCompare)
PeriodPosition = InStr(1 + PeriodPosition, Datastring, ".", vbTextCompare)

Cells(i, 27).Value = Left(Datastring, PeriodPosition - 1)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If 23.1 is different from 23.10, then they are not numbers to begin with. If they are not numbers, you should keep them as strings, for which format the cells as "Text" before assigning the value.

Answer (score 0):

As @GSerg noted in the comments, the OP is not dealing with numbers, but with identifiers. Identifiers are usually best handled as strings.

Treat this as an array, which can be split and joined.

```
Dim DataElements as Variant
Dim SelectedElements as Variant
DataElements = Split(Cells(i, 26).value, ".") '<-- create an array out of the elements
SelectedElements = Array(DataElements(0), DataElements(1)) '<-- create a new array of only the wanted elements

Cells(i, 27).value = "='" & Join(SelectedElements,".") 
' The =' at the start will force the entry to be a string, and not automatically interpreted as a number
' Otherwise, you could format the column to be Text rather than General
```

The above will preserve the strings as originally presented.

> Cells(i, 26).value: 23.10.847475993.38.12039
>
> DataElements: 23, 10, 847475993, 38, 12039
>
> SelectedElements:  23, 10
>
> Cells(i, 27).value: ='23.10

Second case

> Cells(i, 26).value: 23.1.875934.28301.23814
>
> DataElements: 23, 1, 875934, 28301, 23814
>
> SelectedElements:  23, 1
>
> Cells(i, 27).value: ='23.1

Comment: This works to keep the zeros but it would affect the vlookups later on where I would have formulas that would take that string and find it in a different table. So in order for the vlookup to work, the table would also need to have apostrophes at the beginning. So I used something similar to your idea to try to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of @AJD's answer, I modified the code so that there wouldn't be an apostrophe since the string would be used in a vlookup. I'm not much of a coder so this is what I got to work with formulas but I'm sure there is a better and quicker way.

```
Dim DataElements1 As String
Dim DataElements2 As String
Dim SelectedElements As Variant

DataElements1 = Split(Cells(i, 26).Value, ".")(0)
DataElements2 = Split(Cells(i, 26).Value, ".")(1)

Cells(i, 27).Formula = "=" & DataElements1 & "&"".""&" & DataElements2 & ""
Range("AA3:AA" & RowCount).Copy
Range("AA3:AA" & RowCount).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```